# Hide out of stock price but product need to be showing on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

**I have an in issue Magento 1.9**

1. I want to hide product price when it's out of stock but item needs
   to be showing on the website.
2. Only hide price and it will show out of stock.

I tried these codes but get no result

RWD Theme:

> Magento_root/app/design/frontend/rwd/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Change

```
<div class="price-info">
    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
</div>
```

To:

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="price-info">
        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: why do you use tags for m1 and m2?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need modify the following template of the default theme of the RWD design package:

> Magento_root/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Please use the following code:

```
<?php if ($_product->getIsInStock()): ?>
    <div class="price-info">
        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```